# Inserting dictionary from data in Postgresql

Tags: sql, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have followed other posts related to inserting a dictionary into a Postgresql. The syntax is as follows:

```
sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO table_results (id, name, state, response, duration_time) VALUES (%(id)s, %(name)s, %(response)s, %(duration_time)s);'
```

The dictionary has the following data:

```
data= {'id': 29, 'name': "ABC'S KINDERGARDEN", 'response': 'OK', 'duration_time': 60}
```

Then, I can execute the insert statement:

```
db.session.execute(sql_insert,data_dict )
```

However, the previous throws the next error:

```
(psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 1: ...1, result_response, result_duration_secs) VALUES (%(id)s, %(...
                                                             ^
[SQL: INSERT INTO table_results (id, name, state, response, duration_time) VALUES (%%(id)s, %%(name)s, %%(state)s, %%(response)s, %%(duration_time)s);]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)
```

I have tried several ways with this as the most general accepted format.

The following snippet includes the import and code:

```
import psycopg2   
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

sql_insert = "INSERT INTO table_results (" + ", ".join(data_dict.keys()) + ") VALUES (" + ", ".join(["%("+k+")s" for k in data_dict]) + ");"

db.session.execute(sql_insert,data_dict )    

db.session.commit()
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a full code block with `import` lines? Error does not seem to match posted SQL. And you appear to be using `sqlalchemy`. Can't see anything immediately wrong with posted code unless you are using a different DB-API than `psycopg2`.

Comment: sure @Parfait, I posted the code related. Thanks :)

Comment: Looks to me this section `VALUES (%%(id)s, %%(name)s, %%(state)s ...` is causing the problem. Something is escaping/doubling up the '%' and that is causing `%(id)s` to be passed as the actual value instead of the result of `data_dict['id']`

Comment: `Session.execute()` works as if you had wrapped the statement with `text()`, so the % are escaped. Use `:named` style placeholders instead.